# How does Laravel know the request uri when working behind Nginx?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, fastcgi

I'm using Laravel, but I assume it could be any PHP framework (e.g. Symfony).

I have the following Nginx config:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location = /index.php {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

I'm making this request and everything works fine:

```
GET /v3/action/1332899709/some-endpoint?page=1
```

As far as I understand, nginx transforms this request to just `/index.php?page=1`. So, why does this work? **How does Laravel know what uri have I requested?** Does nginx pass some request data "under the hood", while checking endpoints in `try_files`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routing is done with the help of `fastcgi_params`, such as `SCRIPT_FILENAME`, `REQUEST_URI` etc.